# How do non-local neural networks relate to attention and self-attention?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, papers, attention

I've been reading non-local neural networks as explained in [the original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07971). My understanding is that they solve the restrained reception of local filters. I see how they are different from convolutions and fully connected networks.

How do they relate to attention (specifically self-attention)? How do they integrate this attention?